# Problems with bidirectional relationship in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities: Sale and SaleProduct.

I am trying to persist the Sale entity, but I don't know how to make a service to it, because always that I try to save a Sale ir requires a SaleProduct.

This is the Sale entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Sale {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @NotNull(message = "Sale product!")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SALE_ID")
    private List<SaleProduct> products;

    @NotNull(message = "Sale needs some value!")
    private int saleValue;

    private Date creationDate = new Date();

}
```

And here is the SaleProduct entity:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class SaleProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    private int quantity;

    @NotNull(message = "Insert the product, please")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Sale sale;

}
```

I am trying to persist the Sale with this method:

```
    public void insertSale(Sale sale) throws Exception {
        Product product = manager.find(Product.class, 2L);
        SaleProduct saleProduct = new SaleProduct();
        saleProduct.setProduct(product);
        sale.setProducts(Arrays.asList(saleProduct));
        saleProduct.setSale(sale);
        manager.persist(sale);
    }
```

I am sending this JSON:

```
{
    "saleValue" : "200"
}
```

When I try to select the sale I created I get these errors:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.tax.entity.Sale.products, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.tax.entity.Sale["products"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:190)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:674)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(CollectionSerializer.java:160)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:102)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:251)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:846)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.writeTo(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:207)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:131)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:60)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:120)
at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(DigitalSigningInterceptor.java:145)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:124)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:124)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:98)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:466)
... 33 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.tax.entity.Sale.products, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:567)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:205)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:146)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:261)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:88)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
... 50 more
```

One more problem: when I `saleProduct.setSale(sale);` I get this exception: com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method

Comment: Can you show us the error message?

Comment: @Paul of course. Sorry for forget it. Tomorrow I will paste the error here and improve the question.

Comment: @PaulWasilewski I added the erros I'm getting.

Comment: You mean, why do you get "No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'com.tax.entity.Product'. Check configuration for 'product'" ? You haven't got a "bean-validation API" validator for that annotation. Nothing to do with JPA. You cannot put `@Size` on a single-valued relation field!

Comment: @NeilStockton but it's just one of the Exceptions. Solve this problem is not so hard.

Comment: A transaction fails for an exception. An exception has a nested exception etc etc. If you had simply put the FULL STACK TRACE with all nested exceptions then people could understand what problem you have! The BeanValidation exception is the only concrete exception I see, which could cause the others ... i.e root cause

Comment: Oh, thanks @NeilStockton
The full stack trace is too long. Is it a problem to put it here?

Comment: add it in the question (formatted), the important bit is the root cause ... the stuff at the end

Comment: @NeilStockton this is the exception that appears in the end of the console, the root cause, as you said.

Comment: so fix it as my answer says and see what happens

Comment: @NeilStockton you were right! I changed my `@Size` annotation to `@NotNull` and it worked. Now I'm getting another exception, but it's persisting.

Comment: well if that exception was not the purpose of your question then don't post it and put the real question!

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish bidirectional mapping , you got to have "mappedBy" property in OneToMany annotation

In the entity Sale use

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="product", cascade=cascadeType.ALL, fetch=fetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: Can you read the question again? I changed something following the answer given by @ujulu

Answer (score 0):

1. The `@JoinColumn` annotation must be on the onwing side the relationship, that is, it should be on the `@ManyToOne` annotation:

   ```
   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "SALE_ID")
   private Sale sale;
   ```
2. The `mappedBy` attribute must be placed on the inverse side, that is where `@OneToMany` annotation is used:

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="sale" cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<SaleProduct> products;
   ```
3. Create an instance of `Sale`, say `sale`.
4. Create an instance of `SaleProduct`, say `saleProduct`.
5. Add `saleProduct` into the list `products`. (I don't know why you named the list `products` even though it is containing `SaleProduct`s).
6. Assign `sale` to `saleProduct`: `saleProduct.setSale(sale)`. Now both entity instances are wired together.
7. And at last persist: `entityManager.persist(sale);`

Comment: Not successfull. I updated the question. Can you review it?

Comment: I saw your comment too late. Anyway, it seems your problem ist solved; the mapping should also be OK now, if I understood your comment above correctly.

Comment: Yeah @ujulu I'm just getting some errors to fetch the data, but that is another history. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped you. What error do you get while fetching?

Comment: can you take a look here?

Comment: It seems your Hibernate session is closed. Your `products` relationship is lazily loaded by default. If you serialize the sales object before accessing this property before closing the transaction then you will get this exception. So try to access this property by, for example, calling `sale.getProducts().size()` before closing the transaction. Otherwise, if you are using Hibernate look at [the solution to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574236/org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-sess).

Comment: I'm using JTA, so I'm not handling the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says

```
No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'com.tax.entity.Product'. Check configuration for 'product'
```

So remove `@Size` from the field "*product*" since it is not a collection field. You could put it on the other side of the relation `"Sale.products"`

Comment: What you said is correct. I won't vote for accept this answer because it's not the purpose of my question.
But thank you very much, it will help me a lot!