# could not initialize proxy - no Session in @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a domain object called User with this property

```
 @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="t_user_fav_hotel",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="hotel_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<hotel> favoriteHotels = new HashSet<>();
```

I've created a method in the service level to get all the favorites and avoid the error **could not initialize proxy**  and it works fine.

```
userService.getFavorites (loggedInUser());
```

But I don't know how to add a new Hotel avoiding this error:

```
Hibernate.initialize(loggedInUser().getFavoriteHotels());
loggedInUser().getFavoriteHotels().add(hotel);
```

I also added in the user service level with the same result

```
 @Transactional
    public void addFavorite (User user, Hotel hotel) {

            Hibernate.initialize(user.getFavoriteHotels());

            if (!user.getFavoriteHotels().contains(hotel)) {
                user.getFavoriteHotels().add(hotel);
                userRepository.save(user);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - could not initialize proxy - no Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574236/org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-sess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I don't know how to add a new Hotel avoiding this error

When you try to add a new hotel, you are trying to make a new transaction to the database as well, therefore you need to have an open session so you can make this transaction.

I see that you are using Spring so what you can do here is to add a [**`@transactional` annotation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) to the method where you are trying to add a new favorite hotel.

```
@Transactional
public void addNewHotel(Hotel hotel){
   Hibernate.initialize(loggedInUser().getFavoriteHotels());
   loggedInUser().getFavoriteHotels().add(hotel);
}
```