# Initialize lazy collections

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I'm developing a Struts2 + Spring + Hibernate webapp and I need to initialize a lazy collection after retrieving an object or a collection of that object.

**Use case**

I have a **team** model with a relation eagerly loaded called **employees** (I think it's obvious that this is a collection). In turn, **employee** model has a lazy relation **registry** that I need just for some specific actions so I don't need at all to load it eagerly.

Now. I call my `teamService` (injected to my Struts2 controller with Spring) in order to retrieve a specific `teamItem` which has already his collection **employees** loaded. Now it's time to load for each employee its registry relation.

Using the `employeeService` (also this injected to my Struts2 controller with Spring) I call the `initializeCollections()` method of his DAO that should load the lazy collection calling

```
Hibernate.initialize(employee.getRegistry());
```

When I perform this action a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` exception is thrown.

*stack trace:*

```
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize(Hibernate.java:414) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at web.bkgd.simba.dao.registry.RegistryEmployeeDAO.initializeCollections(RegistryEmployeeDAO.java:438) ~[RegistryEmployeeDAO.class:?]
at web.bkgd.simba.service.abstractions.BaseService.initializeCollections(BaseService.java:142) ~[BaseService.class:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266) ~[spring-tx-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1302.initializeCollections(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at web.bkgd.simba.controller.ajax.agenda.TeamController.doSomething(TeamController.java:177) ~[AjaxTeamController.class:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:870) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:?]
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:?]
at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:?]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1369) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:?]
at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:?]
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:?]
at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:?]
at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:?]
at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:?]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$2.execute(OgnlUtil.java:309) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:340) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:307) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:423) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:287) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:250) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at web.bkgd.simba.utility.interceptors.SessionCleanInterceptor.intercept(SessionCleanInterceptor.java:86) ~[SessionCleanInterceptor.class:?]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41) ~[struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) ~[struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76) ~[struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73) ~[struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125) ~[struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91) ~[struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253) ~[struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) ~[struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) ~[xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189) [xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at web.bkgd.simba.utility.interceptors.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:113) [LoginInterceptor.class:?]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244) [xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) [struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564) [struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81) [struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99) [struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar:2.3.24.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.61]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.61]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_79]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.61]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_79]
```

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a different way to load that lazy collection?

**EDIT 01-12-2015**

I've tried to follow *Predrag Maric* answer and I have a little edit to do since seems still not working.

So:

> 1. Implement Open Session in View pattern

No way. This solution may cause a very deep loading of the relations expecially for JSON serialization. Of course I can always define the `<param name="includeProperties">` tag and load just what I need, but I'm still a little scared of the performances.

> 2. Initialize whatever you need in the first service

And here is the point. I've changed my action and DAO structure in order to implement this function. I've used a little of reflection in order to create a general method that I can use in every single DAO of my application.

How it works is very simple:

**Example**

INPUT:

- beanClass: Team
- model: team with no relations loaded
- relations: List:{"relation", "relation.childRelation.grandChildRelation"}

The method for the first string simply calls `Hibernate.initialize()` method and for the second one splits the string in order to load:

- realation, returns `initializeRelations(relation.class, relation, "childRelation.grandChildRelation");`
- childRelation, returns `initializeRelations(childRelation.class, childRelation, "grandChildRelation");`
- grandChildRelation;

Here you have the code:

**TEAM DAO**

These methods are called after a team bean or a list of team beans has been loaded from the database

```
/**
 * Initialize relations. This method returns true if a correct
 * initialization of the relation has been made by hibernate, false in any
 * other case. If the relations object is a List, the method recursively
 * call himself in order to initialize every single instance of the list.
 * If the relations string contains a "." it means that a grandchild
 * relation has to be loaded.
 *
 * @param beanClass
 * @param model
 * @param relations
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean initializeRelations(Class beanClass, BaseModel model, Object relations) {
    // Check if relations is a List
    if (relations instanceof List) {
        // Recursively call initializeRelations
        for (String relation : (List<String>) relations) {
            return initializeRelations(beanClass, model, relation);
        }
    } else if (relations instanceof String) {
        // If relations contains "." then a grandChild relation has to be loaded.
        if (((String) relations).contains(".")) {
            String[] childRelations = ((String) relations).split("\\.");

            // Initialize the child relation
            Object newChildRelations = initializeRelation(beanClass, model, childRelations[0]);

            if (newChildRelations == null) {
                return false;
            } else if (newChildRelations instanceof BaseModel) {
                initializeRelations(newChildRelations.getClass(), model, (Object[]) Arrays.copyOfRange(childRelations, 1, childRelations.length));
            } else if (newChildRelations instanceof List) {
                for (Object newChildRelation : childRelations) {
                    initializeRelations(newChildRelation.getClass(), model, (Object[]) Arrays.copyOfRange(childRelations, 1, childRelations.length));
                }
            }
        } else {
            Object newChildRelations = initializeRelation(beanClass, model, (String) relations);

            return newChildRelations == null;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private Object initializeRelation(Class beanClass, BaseModel model, String relation) {
    try {
        for (PropertyDescriptor pd : Introspector.getBeanInfo(beanClass).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            if (pd.getReadMethod() != null && !"class".equals(pd.getName()) && relation.toLowerCase().equals(pd.getName().toLowerCase()) && pd.getReadMethod().invoke(model) == null) {
                Hibernate.initialize(pd.getReadMethod().invoke(model));

                return pd.getReadMethod().invoke(model);
            }
        }
    } catch (IntrospectionException ex) {
        LOG.warn("Cannot initialize ralation", ex);
    } catch (HibernateException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        LOG.warn("Cannot initialize ralation", ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But what I see in my log is that just the first relation is loaded

```
[DEBUG] 01-12-2015 14:06:52 Controller - relation: Employee{data1="data1", data2="data2", data3="data3", data4="data4", data5="data5"}
[DEBUG] 01-12-2015 14:06:52 Controller - child: [!!!model.Registry_$$_javassist_17@75ce9b7d=>org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:could not initialize proxy - no Session!!!]
```

Comment: 'but I'm still a little scared of the performances.' Yes, but until you have tried and profiled.....Much of the criticism written about OSIV (at least the Spring implementation) is factually incorrect. It is the simplest and most transparent solution **and need not be all or nothing**: in line with 'do the simplest thing that will work' give it a try and optimize further up the stack in those cases where OSIV has too high an overhead.

Comment: Just a note: in your `initializeRelations` method you don't handle the case when `relations` is an array, yet you pass an array there: `(Object[]) Arrays.copyOfRange(...)`

Comment: It would never be an array. Or better... the "parent" method, the one that calls `initializeRelations()`, always creates a list. The `relations instanceOf String` statement is used only if `initializeRelations()` is recursively called. But thanks for your note

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the some problem a few months ago.
I have solved it setting a parameter in my session factory builder.

Try setting the parameter "hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" to your hibernate config.

```
sfBuilder.getProperties().put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans",
            "true");
```

This parameter solved my problem. Hope it helps.

Edited:
Use with caution. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362831/solve-hibernate-lazy-init-issue-with-hibernate-enable-lazy-load-no-trans).

Comment: [Use with caution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362831/solve-hibernate-lazy-init-issue-with-hibernate-enable-lazy-load-no-trans)

Comment: Your answer solved my problem. Opinions about this parameter differ among the web and ofcourse the N+1 problem is always around the corner, but atm seems to work without many problems. So thank you @RodrigoAlmeida

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `Hibernate.initialize()` to initialize lazy relations, but this requires an active Hibernate session. You are

1. Calling `teamService` from the controller (one transaction)
2. Calling `employeeService` with the results of the first call (another transaction)

Your entities are detached from the session after the first call (correct me if I'm wrong, I assumed you've configured transactions on service layer), so this fails. You should either

1. Implement [Open Session in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103363/why-is-hibernate-open-session-in-view-considered-a-bad-practice) pattern
2. Initialize whatever you need in the first service

As for 2., if this service is used in other places which don't need `employee.registry` initialized, you can use a parameter to control initialization

```
teamService.getTeam(id, init);
// and then in getTeam()
if (init) {
    Hibernate.initialize(employee.getRegistry());
}
```

To make this more generic, you can create a `InitConfig` class, which would be passed to each service that needs this kind of behavior. You just add specific parameters in it as you need them.

```
public class InitConfig {
    ...
    private boolean initRegistry;
    ...
}

teamService.getTeam(id, initConfig);
// and then in getTeam()
if (initConfig.getInitRegistry()) {
    Hibernate.initialize(employee.getRegistry());
}
```

Comment: I still receive a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:could not initialize proxy - no Session!!!` error. Can you please have a look at my edit?