# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: customerNumber of:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I've following query which is working fine on mysql. The same I wanted to implement through the `spring-data-jpa` `querydsl API`.

```
select c.* from orders o, customers c where o.customerNumber=103 and c.customerNumber=103;
```

[image]

```
CustomerRepository.java
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer>,
    QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Customer>{

    @Query("select c from Customer c where c.country='USA'")
    List<Customer> findByCountry();

    @Query("select c from Order o, Customer c where o.customerNumber=:customerNumber and c.customerNumber=:customerNumber")
    List<Customer> findByCustomerNumber(@Param("customerNumber") Integer customerNumber);
}
```

But when I run the code, I see following error comes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: customerNumber of: net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Order [select c from net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Order o, net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Customer c where o.customerNumber=:customerNumber and c.customerNumber=:customerNumber]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1374)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: customerNumber of: net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Order [select c from net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Order o, net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Customer c where o.customerNumber=:customerNumber and c.customerNumber=:customerNumber]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1967)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:882)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4426)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3898)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2076)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2001)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1703)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    ... 60 more
```

Test case which I developed:

```
@Test
    public void testCustomerOrder(){
        List<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findByCustomerNumber(103);
        System.out.println("CUSTOMETS : "+customers);
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            System.out.println("================================");
            System.out.println(customer.getCustomerNumber());
            System.out.println(customer.getCustomerName());
            System.out.println(customer.getContactFirstName());
            System.out.println(customer.getContactLastName());
            System.out.println(customer.getPhone());
            System.out.println(customer.getAddressLine1());
            System.out.println(customer.getAddressLine2());
            System.out.println(customer.getCity());
            System.out.println(customer.getState());
            System.out.println(customer.getPostalCode());
            System.out.println(customer.getCountry());
            System.out.println(customer.getCreditLimit());

            List<Order> orders = customer.getOrders();
            for (Order order : orders) {
                System.out.println("-------------------------");
                System.out.println(order.getOrderNumber());
                System.out.println(order.getOrderDate());
                System.out.println(order.getRequiredDate());
                System.out.println(order.getShippedDate());
                System.out.println(order.getStatus());
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Order.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
@NamedQuery(name="Order.findAll", query="SELECT o FROM Order o")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int orderNumber;

    @Lob
    private String comments;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date orderDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date requiredDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date shippedDate;

    private String status;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Orderdetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order")
    private List<Orderdetail> orderdetails;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Customer
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customerNumber")
    private Customer customer;

    // setters and getters
}
```

Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customers")
@NamedQuery(name="Customer.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Customer c")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int customerNumber;

    private String addressLine1;

    private String addressLine2;

    private String city;

    private String contactFirstName;

    private String contactLastName;

    private String country;

    private double creditLimit;

    private String customerName;

    private String phone;

    private String postalCode;

    private String state;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="salesRepEmployeeNumber")
    private Employee employee;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Order
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
    private List<Order> orders;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Payment
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
    private List<Payment> payments;
    // setters and getters
}
```

**Any pointers from experts asap?**

**EDIT-1: I tried below, but still errors are coming:**

```
@Query("select c from Customer c where c.orders.customerNumber=:customerNumber and c.customerNumber=:customerNumber")
    List<Customer> findByCustomerNumber(@Param("customerNumber") Integer customerNumber);
```

Error comes for above configuration:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List net.javabeat.springdata.repository.CustomerRepository.findByCustomerNumber(java.lang.Integer)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: customerNumber of: net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Order [select c from net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Customer c where c.orders.customerNumber=:customerNumber and c.customerNumber=:customerNumber]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1374)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: customerNumber of: net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Order [select c from net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Customer c where c.orders.customerNumber=:customerNumber and c.customerNumber=:customerNumber]
```

ER Diagram:
[image]

**Edit-2: Per suggestion from @Andy, I can access data but seeing following error too**

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Customer.orders, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266)
    at net.javabeat.springdata.CustomerTest.testCustomerOrder(CustomerTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

[image]

Comment: Try this

`select c from Order o, Customer c where o.customer=:customerNumber and c.customerNumber=:customerNumber` and let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Pragnani - With ur suggestion - I see org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [103] did not match expected type [net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Customer (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [103] did not match expected type [net.javabeat.springdata.jpa.data.Customer (n/a)]

Comment: @javatechnology may be possible java could not understand customerNumber param("customerNum") change it to customerNum then check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Query("select c from Customer c where c.orders.customerNumber=:customerNumber and c.customerNumber=:customerNumber")`

You try to access the `customerNumer`attributein `Order`, but I do not see an attribute called `customeNumber`. You only have a `orderNumber`.

`@Query("select c from Customer c, Order o where o.customer.customerNumber=:customerNumber and c.customerNumber=:customerNumber")`

But I am not that sure what you actually want to achieve. Do you want all orders by a customer?

Comment: Ok, I had this error a way to often with spring and I'm not sure how to solve this correctly!
First, the error occurs when you read an object from database and after reading the session is closed. After it you access an object`s property which wasn't loaded from database (lazy loading). Then JPA wants to try to load it, but the session is already closed.

You could try adding @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) on customer.

Comment: Hi, I am able to resolve this error by setting <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop> in springContext.xml, Could you please update ur answer?

Comment: 1st of all, as I said, use EAGER instead of LAZY.
2nd, I think I didn't look right. It causes when you are asking for customer's orders. So try to add `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` to  `@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) private List<Order> orders;`

It will disable Lazy-Loading, but could solve your problem first.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will be definitely trying for that now. But if I kept my original code (with ur modified query) and add @Transactional to Testcase class resolves all problems. Pls guide now

Comment: Fyi: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362831/solve-hibernate-lazy-init-issue-with-hibernate-enable-lazy-load-no-trans)

yeah, I forgot about @Transactional. This should also solve your problem, because session is open as long as the transaction is not committed.

What do you mean with "guide now"?^^

Comment: Your @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) suggestion worked too without @Transactional on TestCases. Which approach we should be following ? Thanks for great help..

Comment: I would recommend not to set this hibernate property, but using @Transactional with Lazy Loading
So you can have all advantages: You do not lower your isolation level (you  are save against repeatable read).You have lazy loading, which is fine and useful for much data, but not always necessary and sometimes (as you see here) disturbing. Sounds like a disadvantages, but I dont think that you want to load all hundred of orders for a customer every time.