# failed to lazily initialize exception

Tags: hibernate, jersey, lazy-evaluation

While i try to pull entity from the database i get the next exception:

```
2018-12-17 10:32:32,483 INFO  [org.Roper.WebService.Resource.BusinessResource] (default task-3) Adding the business: aa.
2018-12-17 10:32:32,502 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (default task-3) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: swap
    ...]
2018-12-17 10:32:32,522 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (default task-3) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2018-12-17 10:32:32,531 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (default task-3) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2018-12-17 10:32:32,531 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (default task-3) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@2274d1cb
2018-12-17 10:32:32,533 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (default task-3) Envers integration enabled? : true
2018-12-17 10:32:32,540 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (default task-3) HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: org.Roper.WebService.Model.BusinessOwner
2018-12-17 10:32:32,547 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (default task-3) HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: org.Roper.WebService.Model.Tourist
2018-12-17 10:32:32,668 INFO  [org.Roper.RoperRestUtils.JpaUtils] (default task-3) Entity manager factory created successfully.
2018-12-17 10:32:32,669 INFO  [org.Roper.RoperRestUtils.JpaUtils] (default task-3) Creating the query: SELECT p FROM Businesd p WHERE p.name='aa'
2018-12-17 10:32:32,671 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (default task-3) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2018-12-17 10:32:32,688 INFO  [org.Roper.WebService.Service.BusinessService] (default task-3) Success, business created.
2018-12-17 10:32:32,690 INFO  [org.Roper.WebService.Service.BusinessService] (default task-3) Success, business owner created.
2018-12-17 10:32:32,690 INFO  [org.Roper.RoperRestUtils.JpaUtils] (default task-3) Entity manager factory is closed.
2018-12-17 10:32:32,692 SEVERE [org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller] (default task-3) Generating incomplete JSON
2018-12-17 10:32:32,693 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /WebService/webapi/BusinessService/business: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.Roper.WebService.Model.Business.businessOwners, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.Roper.WebService.Model.Business.businessOwners, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:584)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller.serializeRoot(Marshaller.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller.marshall(Marshaller.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.toJson(JsonBinding.java:98)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.writeTo(JsonBindingProvider.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1135)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:662)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:395)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:385)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    ... 43 more

>2018-12-17 10:32:42,696 INFO  [org.Roper.WebService.Resource.BusinessResource] (default task-4) Adding the business: aa.
2018-12-17 10:32:42,707 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (default task-4) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: swap
    ...]
2018-12-17 10:32:42,714 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (default task-4) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2018-12-17 10:32:42,720 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (default task-4) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2018-12-17 10:32:42,720 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (default task-4) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@2274d1cb
2018-12-17 10:32:42,722 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (default task-4) Envers integration enabled? : true
2018-12-17 10:32:42,726 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (default task-4) HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: org.Roper.WebService.Model.BusinessOwner
2018-12-17 10:32:42,734 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (default task-4) HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: org.Roper.WebService.Model.Tourist
2018-12-17 10:32:42,826 INFO  [org.Roper.RoperRestUtils.JpaUtils] (default task-4) Entity manager factory created successfully.
2018-12-17 10:32:42,826 INFO  [org.Roper.RoperRestUtils.JpaUtils] (default task-4) Creating the query: SELECT p FROM Businesd p WHERE p.name='aa'
2018-12-17 10:32:42,828 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (default task-4) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2018-12-17 10:32:42,840 INFO  [org.Roper.WebService.Service.BusinessService] (default task-4) Success, business created.
2018-12-17 10:32:42,841 INFO  [org.Roper.WebService.Service.BusinessService] (default task-4) Success, business owner created.
2018-12-17 10:32:42,841 INFO  [org.Roper.RoperRestUtils.JpaUtils] (default task-4) Entity manager factory is closed.
2018-12-17 10:32:42,842 SEVERE [org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller] (default task-4) Generating incomplete JSON
2018-12-17 10:32:42,842 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /WebService/webapi/BusinessService/business: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.Roper.WebService.Model.Business.businessOwners, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.Roper.WebService.Model.Business.businessOwners, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:584)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at
```

The classes:

```
package org.Roper.WebService.Model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name="Business_owners")
@XmlRootElement
public class BusinessOwner extends Person{


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "business_person",   
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "businessOwner_id") },   
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "business_id") }
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    Set<Business> businesses = new HashSet<Business>();

    public BusinessOwner() {
        super();
    }

    public BusinessOwner(Set<Business> businesses) {
        super();
        this.businesses = businesses;
    }

    public Set<Business> getBusinesses() {
        return businesses;
    }

    public void setBusinesses(Set<Business> businesses) {
        this.businesses = businesses;
    }

}




public Business(String name, Category category, boolean onPromotion, String location, Set<Product> products,
        Set<BusinessOwner> businessOwners) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.category = category;
    this.onPromotion = onPromotion;
    this.location = location;
    this.products = products;
    this.businessOwners = businessOwners;
}

public void CopyBusiness(Business newBusiness) {
    this.name = newBusiness.getName();
    this.location = newBusiness.getLocation();
    this.onPromotion = newBusiness.isOnPromotion();
    this.category = newBusiness.getCategory();
    this.products = newBusiness.getProducts();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}
public boolean isOnPromotion() {
    return onPromotion;
}
public void setOnPromotion(boolean onPromotion) {
    this.onPromotion = onPromotion;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
public Set<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}
public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

public Set<BusinessOwner> getBusinessOwners() {
    return businessOwners;
}

public void setBusinessOwners(Set<BusinessOwner> businessOwners) {
    this.businessOwners = businessOwners;
}
```

}

and the second one:

```
package org.Roper.WebService.Model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name="businesses")
@XmlRootElement
public class Business extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{


    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Category category;
    @Column(name="on_promotion")
    private boolean onPromotion;
    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;
    @Column(name="products")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="business")
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="businesses")  
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<BusinessOwner> businessOwners = new HashSet<>();  

    public Business() {
        super();
    }

    public Business(String name, Category category, boolean onPromotion, String location, Set<Product> products,
            Set<BusinessOwner> businessOwners) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.onPromotion = onPromotion;
        this.location = location;
        this.products = products;
        this.businessOwners = businessOwners;
    }

    public void CopyBusiness(Business newBusiness) {
        this.name = newBusiness.getName();
        this.location = newBusiness.getLocation();
        this.onPromotion = newBusiness.isOnPromotion();
        this.category = newBusiness.getCategory();
        this.products = newBusiness.getProducts();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public boolean isOnPromotion() {
        return onPromotion;
    }
    public void setOnPromotion(boolean onPromotion) {
        this.onPromotion = onPromotion;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public Set<BusinessOwner> getBusinessOwners() {
        return businessOwners;
    }

    public void setBusinessOwners(Set<BusinessOwner> businessOwners) {
        this.businessOwners = businessOwners;
    }

}
```

Comment: And the question:

Comment: The hint: you are invoking the lazy `getBusinessOwner()` on a detached instance of `Business`. Detached means the Hibernate Session that has loaded the `Business` instance is already closed.

Comment: How i can keep it open? 
I am trying to update the business owner with the new business is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The StackTrace tells you are trying to convert your Hibernate Entity to JSON and the used JSON converter somehow ignores the `@JsonIgnore`. You might end up serializing your entire data base or receive the glory StackOverflowException.

Comment: And what can i do about the JsonIgnore being ignored?

Comment: I don't know - but regarding the handling of detached objects I'd suggest further reading here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached  and additionaly the controversary `enable_lazy_loading_no_trans` Hibernate setting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362831/solve-hibernate-lazy-init-issue-with-hibernate-enable-lazy-load-no-trans#25367976