# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session Best Practice

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a crud application on few classes : Role, Player, Team, Region.
(MySql DB)
Here is my test code to check the first entities implementations :

```
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.aleki.loltournamenttracking.models.Player;
import com.aleki.loltournamenttracking.services.PlayersService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LolTournamentTrackingApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private PlayersService playersService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LolTournamentTrackingApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Optional<Player> p1 = playersService.getPlayerById(1);
        Player p = p1.get();
        System.out.println(p.getTeam());
    }

}
```

**=== Entities ===**

```
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;


import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String label;
}
```

```
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
public class Player {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String nickname;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Team team;
}
```

```
import lombok.Data;

import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="teams")
public class Team {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "region_id")
    private Region region;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>();
}
```

```
package com.aleki.loltournamenttracking.models;


import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="regions")
public class Region {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String iso1;
}
```

**=== Repositories ===**

All my reposiotries look the same as this one :

`import com.aleki.loltournamenttracking.models.Player;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface PlayersRepository extends CrudRepository<Player, Long> {}
`

**=== Services ===**
The PlayersServices class I call during my test :

```
import java.util.Optional;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.aleki.loltournamenttracking.models.Player;
import com.aleki.loltournamenttracking.repositories.PlayersRepository;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Service
@Transactional
public class PlayersService {

    @Autowired
    private PlayersRepository repository;

    public Iterable<Player> getPlayers(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Player> getPlayerById(final long id){
        return repository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

**And the execption I got :**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.aleki.loltournamenttracking.models.Team#1] - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:314) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
        at com.aleki.loltournamenttracking.models.Team$HibernateProxy$1dgpTrPu.toString(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:1047) ~[na:na]
        at com.aleki.loltournamenttracking.LolTournamentTrackingApplication.run(LolTournamentTrackingApplication.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
```

I'm trying to make my oneToMany and manyToOne relationship work.

- I try the @Transactionnal annotation.
- I follow tutorials , but it don't look like the best pratices.

I'm looking for a way to fix that , like a company would do , best pratice...
Thx for reading :)

Comment: check it for [best practices](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-transaction-best-practices/) and also for a fix just remove `@Transactional` from Service class. Also i recommend you to have a look through stackOverFlow here are many posts about this problem and how to deal with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve Hibernate Lazy-Init issue with hibernate.enable\_lazy\_load\_no\_trans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362831/solve-hibernate-lazy-init-issue-with-hibernate-enable-lazy-load-no-trans)